# Does YouTube API not support looping in IE9?

Tags: javascript, youtube

So I'm sticking a background video into our webpage, and I have the following code:

```
function setupYoutubeBG(videoId){
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // , This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
        player = new YT.Player('bgPlayer', {

            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'autohide':1, 'wmode':'opaque', 'playlist':videoId, 'loop':1 },
            videoId: videoId,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady}
        });
    }

    // The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
    }
}
```

Which is pretty straightforward, pulled right from the documentation.  Works fine in all browsers including IE11 but for some reason, when testing in IE9 the video doesn't loop. I've set the playlist to the videoId, and like I said, it works everywhere else.   If anybody has an idea or can point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.